# Can we access universal url with in same application?

Tags: deep-linking, ios-universal-links

Can I/we access the universal link from the same application we trying to access.
Ex:
I have xyz application installed in my iPhone
it implemented with universal URL functionality on user clicking on universal url and it working fine when im trying to access from mail/iMessage applications
at same time it had a functionality to create dynamic url inside it and that can be clickable and copied.

currently when I click on link it is not doing any functionality as I click from other application ... can we do that ?